# misunderstanding with Node.js RESTIFY URL mapping

Tags: node.js, url, restify

If I use the barebones echo server demo for restify, it works correctly. But if I make a few changes shown below, it behaves different than I would expect:

```
var restify = require('restify');

function respond(req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.params); //NOTE: should echo back all params
}

var server = restify.createServer();
server.get('/hello/', respond); //NOTE: parameter :name removed

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

What I've done is removed the name param from the URL and echoed all parameters in response function. calling:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

returns

{}

but so does:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello?foo=bar
```

Why don't I see foo:bar in the response?

Comment: fixed by adding server.use(restify.queryParser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that goes after the question mark in the URL are not `params` but `query`, and in order to reference it use: `req.query`.
Try this to echo back all data.

```
function respond(req, res, next) {
  res.send({
    params: req.params,
    query: req.query
  });
}
```

Comment: oh thank you. I like that even better than my previous answer!

Comment: btw, I was originally doing this via POST and was seeing inconsistencies such as when the :name param was in the mapped URL I DID get the query AND params with both POST and GET. That is what confused me.

Comment: For POST data, you need to use `req.body`.

Comment: thanks again for the help Maksims. I will go back and double check the original results that led me to think I should get the params (or body) back. If I can reproduce I may have stumbled on a subtle bug. The behavior should be consistent with or without a variable component of the mapped URL.

Answer (score 0):

I found helpful answers in other post.

Ultimately I needed to add this for GETs

```
server.use(restify.queryParser());
```

and

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
```

for POSTs